# is it possible to replace the default "Force Close" dialog in Android?

Tags: java, android, exception

I would like the users of my android app to have the option to email me the stacktrace of any uncaught exception that crashes my app.  Originally I thought I would just wrap every entry point to my app in a try/catch block, but there are far too many of these even in my tiny app for this to be reasonable.

So what I am really looking for is a way to specify some method to be the default handler for any uncaught exceptions.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don’t understand, isn’t it a standard behaviour of Android. On my phone when an app crash, I can click a button which will send a report containing the stacktrace and other informations.

Comment: Yes, Guillaume, but this question is a year and a half old and that feature was not yet in android.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot do what the subject line states from an SDK application.

However:

> So what I am really looking for is a
>   way to specify some method to be the
>   default handler for any uncaught
>   exceptions. Any suggestions?

Use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`.

Also, consider using Flurry or DroidDrop or something for the actual delivery of your exception data.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use [Bugsense.com](http://www.bugsense.com) to get your exception data (it's free).

PS: I am the founder :)