# Android Exception Handling

Tags: android, exception

We are converting out suite of iPhone apps written in .NEt MonoTouch to Android.

How do we catch, then publish exceptions so that they are reported via the Android Market?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler)
```

There you can catch everything and send mails, notifications, etc.

EDIT:

Check this questions, are basically the same:

- [Global uncaught exception handler -> email log to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654168/global-uncaught-exception-handler-email-log-to-me)
- [is it possible to replace the default “Force Close” dialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314139/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-default-force-close-dialog-in-android)

Answer (score 9):

You should also try [Bugsense.com](http://www.bugsense.com), it's free and allows you to track exceptions in Android.

PS: I am the founder

Comment: Just tried it - pretty cool service. Are you guys planning to charge for this service and how much?

Comment: Everything you see right now, will be free. We plan to charge only for upcoming premium features!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using the library [android-remote-stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/).  It uses the methods Macarse mentions but wraps it in a useful POST to your server, which you can use to put into a database or send an email.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [Android-Error-Reporter](https://github.com/tomquist/Android-Error-Reporter) which POSTs unhandled (or if necessary handled exceptions as well) to your server similar to android-remote-stacktrace but more reliable and it allows you to ask the user before sending the error report.

Answer (score 2):

There's also Google's [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) project (Application Crash Report for Android).

> ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form. It is targetted to android applications developers to help them get data from their applications when they crash or behave erroneously.

A few points about ACRA that are relevant to this question:

> - more detailed crash reports about the device running the app than what is displayed in the Android Market developer console error reports
> - you can add your own variables content or debug traces to the reports
> - you can send error reports even if the application doesn't crash

We recently started using ACRA in [Andromo](http://www.andromo.com) to receive crash reports, since the apps made with Andromo are uploaded to the market by the user who designed the app, and not by us. (Otherwise we'd rely on our users to forward any crash reports to us.)

That it also sends reports for apps that haven't been uploaded to the market is a nice bonus, because we could potentially catch problems while an app is still being tested, before the user uploads it to the market.

Comment: You can also use BugSense and ACRA so you can enjoy the error analytics (ps: I am one of the founders).